# Monitor a text file for a single string/line with Zabbix?

Tags: zabbix

I have a Windows server with an application running on it. Using powershell I'm checking a file from said application for changes (being compared against another file) and outputting the result as a text file on the C:\ drive. That file just contains the string "True" or "False" (not quotes) depending on if the file changed or not.

How can I check this file for a string value? I tried:

```
{myserver:system.run[powershell.exe -Command "Get-Content 'C:\changed.txt' | Select-String 'True' -quiet"].regexp("False")}
```

But all that returns is ??F.

Answer (score 1):

`system.run` is not really needed here. Instead you could use [log file monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items)

```
log["C:\changed.txt",True]
```

Remember, this item must be configured as an [active check](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/appendix/items/activepassive#active_checks)

Comment: Hi @itinneed, if my answer helped you, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.